# How to work on XCode project with more than 1 developer

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I've been working solo on XCode projects for a while now, and in this new project I need to work with several developer. How do I go about that?

I've been using Dropbox for a while and I do know about source control (Git, locally) but I'm using it for my own tracking. How do I branch out and let other developers work on that? Do they open the same project on Dropbox (syncing issues?)? And how do I merge them back again?

Comment: No; you should use a git remote, such as GitHub.

Comment: You must work with Git (GitHub is free) or SVN (I don't know a free one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a service like GitHub to help you with this: https://github.com/

Also, BitBucket is a similar service but has the added benefit of free private repos.

There's no need to resort to DropBox. Both you and the other developer can work on separate branches and merge your code to the master branch as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've heard of github, if its not too much of a hassle, can you brief me on how it is actually suppose to work? It is a separate thing totally from xcode's source control? How do you create the branches and merge the branches since it is online?

Comment: @JustinLeo I'd recommend you understand bit more about source control with git/svn. Have a good browse, there are plenty of resources. Also have a look at "Git Workflows".

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easy deploy with your team using even dropbox directly to a server without understanding how GitHub and/or bitbucket works (optionally, offcource). There are services like http://unbouncepages.com/the-magicbox/ that can be used to connect your local computer to remote FTP/SFTP with Magicbox and start working on your project, your code will be populated on live server at same time.